# UINavigationController poptorootviewcontroller and select another tab makes transition like push a view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller, and each tab has a `UINavigationController`. It's something looks like this:

```
[tab1:UINavigationController,  tab2:UINavigationController, tab3:UINavigationController]
```

tab1 has a view controller which allows a user to post something. Something like this:

```
tab1:rootviewcontroller -> SelectLocationViewController -> CreatePostViewController
```

and Tab 3 is the `viewController` shows whatever user posted, like this

```
tab3:navigationController(rootViewController:PostHistoryViewController)
```

what I want to do is that when user finished post something, it will navigate back to the tab bar controller and select Tab 3. But I want the whole transition looks like pushing a view controller. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use StoryBoardID

```
ViewControllerName *push=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerName"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:push animated:YES];
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully, there are three tabs thus there are three `UINavigationController`. So my current implementation is `poptoviewcontroller` from tab1's `UINavigationController` first and do `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2`, but this transition experience is bad. What I want this process is like "pushing a view controller"